# Spring Cloud Config Server warning (no custom http config)

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I setup Spring Cloud Config Server to work with Git repository. It works fine except the warning like this

```
pClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory : No custom http config found for URL:<URL>
```

What does it mean? What I need to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. The problem was with git uri. I previously set it like:

http://example.com/my-repo

It produces the redirections and eventually the warnings.

I had to use "https" and ".git" in uri like this:

https://example.com/my-repo.git

Now it works fine.